# How to display XML column content in datagrid in windows form?

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagrid

I am using windows forms datagrid. I am filling it from sql table.

```vb
Sub GetRequestLogs() 'From webservices database i.e. Vail-PlantAdgas-Webservices

    Try

        Dim query As String = "GetRequestLogs"
        Dim ConnectionString As String = GetConnectionString()

        Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsInbound", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkboxIsInbound.Checked
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@InterfaceID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbInterfaces.SelectedValue)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbStatuses.SelectedValue)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromLogDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 1000).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtFromDateLogs.Value)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToLogDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtToDateLogs.Value)


                Try

                    Dim sqlDataAdap As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim dtRecord As DataTable = New DataTable()
                    cn.Open()

                    sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord)

                    dgvReturnMessage.DataSource = dtRecord

                    cn.Close()
                Catch inEx As Exception
                    Dim ex As String = inEx.Message
                    Throw inEx
                End Try

            End Using
        End Using
```

But the sql table has one column of type XML and I want to show it as an XML in datagrid too but it's coming simple text.

How should I display it in xml style in winforms?

Comment: XML is plain/simple text, What is 'xml style' according to you? If you mean syntax highlighting for XML, try with the nuget package `FastColoredTextbox`

Comment: If the XML is simply not formatted/indented, you can use the `CellFormatting` event and use the `XDocument.Parse([Current XML String]).ToString()` method to format and indent the *raw* XML.`XDocument` requires a reference to `System.Xml.Linq`.

Comment: This is actually not a bad question (vs some others), which will never get a meaningful answer. However, I can guide you into right directions. Out of the box you will not get what you want. You ether need to dive into nuget/open source sites to see if someone already had written this or do it yourself. Use custom draw for your column. Here is an article that can be your guidance [https://www.codemag.com/Article/0707061/Create-a-Custom-DataGridView-Column]